# Why mysql decide to use index merge though I have already use a unique key index?

Tags: mysql

We found some dead lock case when some update statement occurs in the same time.

From the dead lock logs, we found dead lock occurs between two sql with the same struct but different parameters.

After explain one of the SQL

```
update repay_plan_info_1
 SET actual_pay_period_amount = 20742,

    actual_pay_principal_amount = 19998,

    actual_pay_interest_amount = 726,

    actual_pay_fee = 0,

    actual_pay_fine = 18,

    actual_discount_amount = 0,  

    repay_status = 'PAYOFF',

    repay_type = 'OVERDUE',

    actual_repay_time = '2019-08-12 15:48:15.025' 


 WHERE (  user_id = '938467411690006528'          
              and loan_order_no = 'LN201906130129401690006528175485'
              and seq_no = 2
              and repay_status <> 'PAYOFF' )
```

We found MySQL uses index merge,

[image]

```
           id:1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table:repay_plan_info_1
         type:index_merge
possible_keys:uk_repay_order,idx_user_id
          key:uk_repay_order,idx_user_id
      key_len:102,62
          ref:NULL
         rows:1
       Extra:Using intersect(uk_repay_order,idx_user_id);Using where;Using temporary
```

But we have already defined loan_order_no`+`seq_no` as unque key

```
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `uk_repay_order` (`loan_order_no`,`seq_no`),
 UNIQUE KEY `uk_repay_plan_no` (`repay_plan_no`),
 KEY `idx_user_id` (`user_id`),
 KEY `idx_create_time` (`create_time`)
```

Solution: we delete the index idx_user_id and create another combined index (user_id,loan_order_noseq_no), which solve the dead lock problem.

Question:

1. Why mysql chooses index merge even though I have an unique key defined.
2. When we explain some of the dead lock sql, we found that some of them does not use index merge, but some of them uses, so what may affects mysql's decision, please note that all sql uses the unique key which means thay will always update only one record.

Comment: Please remove the image and replace the result of explain statement in text format; Image is very hard to read.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, it is a pity that we have solve the problem and we can not explain the sql to show the same result, we only have a screenshot that the developer captured at that night. So I can;t have the the text output anymore